# Will the boot time decrease if /boot/ is put in an SSD?

Tags: linux, boot

We have an option to create separate partitions for /boot, /home and root when installing Linux.
So if I create a separate /boot partition on a SSD and create a root partition on a HDD, will the boot time decrease?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is no. The improvement will be miniscule and not noticeable. The OS still needs to load from the slower HDD.

Comment: But don't the boot files reside in the /boot directory?

Comment: boot partition contains only the bootloader. After the bootloader is loaded, it then loads the kernel and other OS modules from the root. 
The bootloader is very small, so the performance gain will not be noticeable.